# Update state with two functions, doesn't update component correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a component with two functions which should update state object:

```
class Categories extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        categoryData: [],
        objects: [],
        object:[],
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        data:data.Dluga,
        categoryData: data.Dluga.basic,
        objects:data,
    })
}
changeCategory(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        categoryData: this.state.data[(event.currentTarget.textContent).split(' ')[1]],
    });
}
changeObject(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const objectOne = Object.assign({}, this.state.objects[event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.children[0].children[0].value]);
    this.setState({
        objects: this.state.objects,
        object:objectOne,
    });

};
render() {
    return (
        <div className='categories'>
            <SelectObejct onValueChange={this.changeObject}/>
            <ul>
                {Object.keys(this.state.data).map((item) => {
                    return (
                        <li className='category' key={item}
                            onClick={this.changeCategory.bind(this)}>
                            <span className='category-item'> {item}</span>
                        </li>
                    )})
                }
            </ul>
            <div>
                <CategoryData categoryData={this.state.categoryData}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

When I update state with `changeObject` I have in state object two properties: `objects` and `object`, but initially it was 4 properties... Next when I update state with `changeCategory` I have initial properties from `componentDidMount` and updated `categoryData` but `object` is empty... I can't update state in one function because it's two `onClick` elements. What should I do to update state correctly?

Comment: In `componentDidMount` where `data` comes from ?

Comment: Also note that you have a syntax error in the above which would prevent it from running at all (the `;` after the end of the method body for `changeObject`). (If that's your real code and you're transpiling and the transpiler is letting you get away with that `;`, file a bug about it with the transpiler project.)

Comment: Sorry, but this component don't make much sense... can you create this in a sandbox ... like codesandbox.io ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary thing you're doing incorrectly is updating state based on existing state without using the callback version of `setState`. State updates can be asynchronous, and can be combined (batched). Any time you're setting state derived from the current state, you [**must** use the callback form](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly). E.g.:

```
changeCategory(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState(prevState = > {
        return {
            categoryData: prevState.data[(event.currentTarget.textContent).split(' ')[1]]
        };
    });
}
```

Note that we're passing it a function, which will get called *later* (only a tiny bit later, but later), and will get the then-current state passed to it as a parameter; and we return the new state as a return value.

> When I update state with `changeObject` I have in state object two properties: `objects` and `object`, but initially it was 4 properties...

That's absolutely normal. It's common to only specify a subset of your state properties when calling `setState`. In fact, `changeObject` should be:

```
changeObject(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState(prevState => {
        const objectOne = Object.assign({}, prevState.objects[event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.children[0].children[0].value]);
        return { object: objectOne };
    });
}
```

Note that I didn't specify `objects: prevState.objects`. There's no reason to if you're not changing it.

> Next when I update state with `changeCategory` I have initial properties from `componentDidMount` and updated `categoryData` but `object` is empty.

`object` will only be empty (whatever "empty" means) if you set it to that at some point. I suspect resolving the above will resolve this issue, but if not, and if you can't figure it out with further debugging, I suggest posting a **new** question with an [mcve] demonstrating that problem (you can do a runnable one with Stack Snippets; [here's how](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/)).